# Merging two Dictionaries with togrther

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary, python-requests

I try to merge two dictionaries with together with out update() method. What is your offer to use with new ways?

Comment: Can you share some code ? You want a different way ? why ? `new_d = {**a, **b}` ?

Comment: Yes sure will share. I try to improve my python skills with new solves

Comment: StackOverflow is more a place to come with issues (and tries) to be solved

Comment: Yes great space to learn more and improve skills

Comment: @But yo may search a bit by yourself first, google "python merge dict" gives a very good start ;)

Comment: Google is useful option to find correct ways.